# Chrome sent duplicate cookie

Tags: google-chrome, spring-mvc, servlets, cookies

I am working on a spring MVC app and found a strange issue that only happen on chrome. The logic is:

1. user request a list of items
2. user click on add new button and a bootstrap dialog popup allow user type in the name
3. on submit, a post request sent to the server
4. server create an new item and save it to db
5. server store the new item id to cookie and send a redirect response to browser
6. browser request item view page
7. server pick up the item id from cookie and render the page

The above logic runs good on nearly all browsers (I didn't test on IE) except chrome. I found the root cause is chrome will store previous cookie with a different item id and at step 6 chrome send duplicate item id cookies to the server.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Chrome[Version 32.0.1700.41 m Aura]
[image]

Opera[Version 20.0.1353.0]
[image]

Firefox[Version 29.0a1 (2013-12-10)]
[image]

Safari[Version 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)]
No screen capture. But it works

Comment: So, did you solve this somehow? I'm having exactly same issue.

Comment: No. what I did is to ignore all previous cookie and process the last one

Comment: I see, that's not an option in my case. But what I did is changed the cookie name from JSESSIONID to SESSIONID, and it magically started working, I have no idea what and where it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Restart Chrome!

At some point (even today this happened to me) Chrome is getting confused on what cookies a domain has in its memory vs cached on disk. This confusion leads to cookies being added but not removed from what I can tell. In my case, I'm Suspecting McAfee locking files for scanning. Restarting Chrome rebuilds the cache and then works.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17855
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=273873

Answer (score 0):

I had something along this stored in my Chrome cookies :

**1st cookie :** (it was set to expire)

- Site : dashboard.app.localhost
- Value : *access-token=123456; Domain=**.app.localhost**; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict*

**2nd cookie :** (session cookie that shouldn't be there, I had to dig in the Chrome settings to find it)

- Site : dashboard.app.localhost
- Value : *access-token=invalid; Domain=**api.app.localhost**; Path=/*

Apparently the second cookie appeared due to an error on my side. However, Chrome sent it alongside the first one, creating this header :

*Cookie: access-token=invalid; access-token=123456*

**The solution I found :**

Manually delete the second cookie in the Chrome settings.